# WPF Localization Language Groups

Tags: wpf, localization

I have a standard WPF localized application using .resx files. At the moment I have support for en-US (default) en-AU, es, and zh-CN.

Do I need to have a separate resx file for each language, or is there some way to group them? For example, I imagine people with region id en-GB would prefer en-AU over en-US. or zh-TW would definitely prefer zn-CN over en-US. I could certainly just copy the files, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You need a seperate resx file for every language and each file has to have the same keys. The matching resx file will be choosen automatically.
You can have one default resx file if that's what you wanted to know, too.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to this question but I just found it so I might as well give an answer.

I guess there are two options, depending on your needs:

You can define a "Resources.en.resx" that en-GB users will fall back to if there is no specific en-GB resource file defined.
en-GB users will try to look for resources in the following order:

1. Resources.en-GB.resx
2. Resources.en.resx
3. Resources.resx

This works per resource entry. You can define all common "en" resources in Resources.en.resx, and only the differences in Resources.en-AU, so you don't have to copy paste all resources.

You can also manually set the culture depending on the language code: if the user is in en-GB, you could just set the culture to en-AU:

```cs
CultureInfo userCulture = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
if(userCulture.Name == "en-AU") // do what you want
```